# PHP detect if search is date or not

Tags: php, date

I have a search box on my website...mysql database. I check currently if the keyword search is a category or just a sentence that matches the title. I would like to enhance that further by detecting if a date is the search keyword, then it will know that and SELECT * posts relevant to that date. How can I detect if it is a date or not? maybe a regular expression?

For your info, I am using the standard format of YYYY/MM/DD so e.g. 2012/07/21.

Comment: split + http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: @KarolyHorvath +1, there's tons of comments on that page that does exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd test it with `strtotime()`.

```
$keyword;

$time = strtotime($keyword);

if ($time !== false) {
  // $keyword is a parsable date!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, referring to doc was helpful and am using this to work it out :D

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) `strtotime()`, which returns a timestamp or FALSE if not a date...

Answer (score 1):

**strtotime** not work for me, because strings and integers are dates. The following code is a much better solution

```
$value_date_array = date_parse($value);
if(checkdate($value_date_array['month'], $value_date_array['day'], $value_date_array['year']))
```